# Running Jupyter Notebook with Different Configurations from CLI

Tags: parameters, jupyter, nbconvert, papermill

I started to use Jupyter Notebook for my project and I use `nbconvert` to run it from the command line.

I want to know that is there any way to have a `.ipynb` file and run it with some command-line arguments or reading from `stdin` somewhere?

I read `nbconvert` documentation but I didn’t find out a way to do it.

If there is no way to do something like those, I want to know what is the best practice to have a single `.ipynb` file and run with different configurations?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a tool named `papermill` for parameterizing and executing Jupyter Notebooks.

Here's a [a link](https://papermill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to its documentation and [how to parameterize your notebook](https://papermill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage-parameterize.html).